# Deploying python to Heroku - Web process failed to bind to $PORT

Tags: python, heroku

I have this python code to deploy to Heroku:

```
import flask
import pandas as pd


def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        """
        Index page view handler.
        :return: rendered index.html template
        """
        return flask.render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def data():
        """
        Data view handler
        :return: JSON object of the data CSV file
        """
        data = pd.read_csv('task_data.csv')

        context = {
            'sensor_data': data.to_dict(orient='list')
        }
        return flask.jsonify(context)

    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    # serve the application on port 7410
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7410)
```

Procfile

```
web: python main.py
```

After I uploaded the files I get now this errors in log view:

> 2020-02-26T14:08:32.485820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:38.283732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `python main.py`
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:41.705572+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Serving Flask app
>   "main" (lazy loading)
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:41.705637+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Environment:
>   production
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:41.705644+00:00 app[web.1]:    WARNING: This is a
>   development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:41.705705+00:00 app[web.1]:    Use a production WSGI
>   server instead.
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:41.705763+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debug mode: off
>
> 2020-02-26T14:08:41.722252+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on
>   http://0.0.0.0:7410/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>
> 2020-02-26T14:09:38.524175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed
>
> 2020-02-26T14:09:38.453425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot
>   timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of
>   launch
>
> 2020-02-26T14:09:38.453485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with
>   SIGKILL
>
> 2020-02-26T14:09:38.509347+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 137

Please advise how to fix this error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What port to use on heroku python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899666/what-port-to-use-on-heroku-python-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know you should take port from environment variables, so it would be:

```
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

which can be found [here](https://blog.heroku.com/python_and_django#heroku-python-quickstart). Also there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899666/what-port-to-use-on-heroku-python-app). Hope this will make it clear.

Comment: I tried to access the url when I used in the code `localhost` but it did not work do I must use the heroku url or I can use localhost ?